# PHP Upload, extract and progressbar

Tags: php, html, upload, progress-bar

I need help with creating a progress bar for my php upload site. I've got the upload and exctract part sorted but i need help with the progress bar. I'm not sure how to do it. Also, is there a maximum file size for the upload?

**HTML**

```
<?php if($message) echo "<p>$message</p>"; ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<label>Choose file (.zip): <input type="file" name="zip_file" /></label>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"]) {
  $filename = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];
  $source = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
  $type = $_FILES["zip_file"]["type"];

  $name = explode(".", $filename);
  $accepted_types = array(
    'application/zip', 
    'application/x-zip-compressed', 
    'multipart/x-zip', 
    'application/x-compressed');                          

  foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
    if($mime_type == $type) {
      $okay = true;
      break;
    } 
  }

  $continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
  if(!$continue) {
    $message = "[...] not a .zip file. Please try again.";
  }
  $target_path = "./".$filename;
  if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $x = $zip->open($target_path);
    if ($x === true) {
      $zip->extractTo("./");
      $zip->close();

      unlink($target_path);
    }
    $message = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";
  } else {  
    $message = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make some changes to fit but this works rather well if you want a progress bar. You can add more eventlisteners and make it how you want. I hope this is a good starting point for you.

```
function uploadFile(){
    var file = document.getElementById("zip_file").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("zip_file", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event) { runprogress(event); } , false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event) {uploadcomplete(event); }, false);
    //Target your php file. 
    ajax.open("POST", "upload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function runprogress(event){
    //The progress %, you might want to Math.round(percent) 
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
}
function uploadcomplete(event){
    //This will = to your php reply.
    var AjaxReply=event.target.responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you would have to use JavaScript to do this. Post your data through an AJAX call and initialize the progress bar. Over time animating it so that the bar "fills up".

Eventually the AJAX call will complete and will send a response back, upon the completion of the call you can finish the animation. This is how I would assume most progress bars work as they typically go up then stop around 99% until the post returns it's "complete status".

In any case, you would have a progress bar, represented by a `<div>` for example, with a width that would increase as time goes on, or a number would go up etc... and you would animate this using JavaScript and/or jQuery. Hopefully this will get you started in the right direction.

**EDIT**

Here's a link to a tutorial describing the steps necessary to upload files to the server using AJAX: [Uploading Files with AJAX](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i'll sure give this one a go!