# File is not uploading using Ajax/JQuery but uploading using Form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl, file-upload, image-uploading

I am trying to upload a file using using Ajax/Jquery, Actual image file is not getting uploaded, instead 0 byte file named "object_FileList" getting created on the destination directory.

This is my JQuery Code.

```
$('#fileUpload').click(function() 
{
    alert ('reached here');
    var photo_data = $("#photo")[0].files; // Getting the properties of file from file field
    var form_data = new FormData(); // Creating object of FormData class
    form_data.append('photo', photo_data);

    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.pl",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data, // Setting the data attribute of ajax with file_data
        type: 'post',
        success : function(response)
        {
            alert ("success");
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        { 

          alert ("script error");


        }, // error 
    });
});
```

HTML Code

```
<input id="photo" type="file" name="photo" />
<button type='button' id='fileUpload' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>
   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-upload'></span> 
   Start Upload
</button>
```

Perl Script

```
#!c:/perl64/bin/perl.exe

use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
use File::Basename;

$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000;
my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";
my $upload_dir = "C:/Users/Public/";

my $cgi = new CGI;
my $filename = $cgi->param("photo");

if ( !$filename )
{
    print $cgi->header ( );
    print "There was a problem uploading your photo (try a smaller file).";
    exit;
}


my ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '..*' );
$filename = $name . $extension;
$filename =~ tr/ /_/;
$filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g;

if ( $filename =~ /^([$safe_filename_characters]+)$/ )
{
    $filename = $1;
}
else
{
    die "Filename contains invalid characters";
}


my $upload_filehandle = $cgi->upload("photo");
print $upload_filehandle;


open UPLOADFILE, ">C:/Users/Public/$filename"  or die $!;
binmode UPLOADFILE;

while ( <$upload_filehandle> )
{
print UPLOADFILE;
}

close UPLOADFILE;

print $cgi->header ();
```

I don't think there is any issue in Perl script because if I'm using form data to upload the file, its uploading perfectly.

```
<form action="upload.pl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="photo" type="file" name="photo" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

Can someone help me what is wrong in first case. (Uploading using Ajax/Jquery)??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image uploader not working with JQuery/ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762446/image-uploader-not-working-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: That is not a accepted answer. I tried that solution but also not working.

Comment: Then you should edit your previous question and add some more information to that question instead of just opening a new question with the same content. If an answer is not working, write it in the comment of the answer!

Comment: You seem to have read my answer to your previous question, fixed the issue I pointed out, and then broken your code in a different way. So this isn't exactly a duplicate, but as @SidBurn said, it would have been better to simply comment on my previous answer. Also, when troubleshooting it helps to only make a single change at a time; you changed several things at once (or the code you posted in your last question wasn't your actual code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked a very similar question yesterday, but seem to have changed a few things and broken your code in a different way. The culprit this time is in your JavaScript code:

```
var photo_data = $("#photo")[0].files;
```

This returns a [FileList object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), which makes the content of your AJAX request look like this:

```
-----------------------------195229089014926488201584712872
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"

[object FileList]
-----------------------------195229089014926488201584712872--
```

This is not going to work, since you're not sending the actual contents of a file. To send the contents of the first file in the list, do:

```
var photo_data = $("#photo")[0].files[0];
```

or, since jQuery isn't necessary here, simply

```
var photo_data = document.getElementById("photo").files[0];
```

This sets the content of the request to something more like:

```
-----------------------------4576019836610138732026194501
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="foo.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

foo
bar

-----------------------------4576019836610138732026194501--
```

Note that you'll have to make additional changes to your code if you actually want to upload a binary file like an image.

Also note that your Perl script has some security holes that should be fixed, notably:

1. Never allow users to determine filenames or paths on your system.
2. Use the 3-argument form of `open`, e.g. `open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$file: $!";`

There are probably more, but those are the ones that jump out at a glance.

---

### A note about troubleshooting

For whatever reason, in the code you posted yesterday you had

```
var file_data = $("#avatar").prop("files")[0];
```

which would also work if you changed the selector to `$("#photo")`. I'm not sure why you made this change, because it broke your otherwise-working JavaScript code.

That's why in troubleshooting, you should only make one change at a time to help isolate the cause of an issue. If you make two changes at once, one might fix your previous issue while the other one introduces a new bug.

Also, I recommend you make liberal use of your browser's developer tools for troubleshooting your JavaScript code. This will allow you to examine the exact parameters and content being sent in your AJAX requests, which is how I tracked down the bugs in both of your questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. I'm able to solve solve the issue with this. surely i'll make necessary changes to perl script to avoid above security holes.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal You're welcome. Glad you got it working.