# How to disabling button choose file upload in php once finished upload file?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

If we have 5 button choose file to upload file and want to disable automatically button once we have finished to do upload for each button, how we can know that "A" button choose file has row "A" in our table db mysql. So if user logged out once upload 3 files, the log in again. He only see 2 buttons choose file that enabled? Thank you for your help.

Here my code :

upload_image.php

```
<table align="center" width="800" height="500" class="tengah">
<tr>
<td align="center"><img src="img/logoo.fw.png"></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<form action="multiple_upload_image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1"     id="form1">
<td align="center"><img src="img/upload.fw.png"><br><br>
1. Select Image : &nbsp;<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" /><br><br>
2. Select Image : &nbsp;<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" /><br><br>
3. Select Image : &nbsp;<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" /><br><br>
4. Select Image : &nbsp;<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" /><br><br>
5. Select Image : &nbsp;<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" align="right"/> </form>
<a href="home.php"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Finished"  align="right"/></a><br><br>
*) Total Max Upload only 10MB
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Here, my php code :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL^(E_NOTICE | E_WARNING));
set_time_limit(0);
session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['userr'];
$password=$_SESSION['passw'];
$user_id=$_SESSION['usr_id'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("person");
if(isset($_FILES['ufile'])){
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['ufile']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['ufile']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 30000000){
    $errors[]='File size must be less than 10 MB';
    }   
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("person");  
$query = "INSERT INTO image (user_id, name, type, size ) ".
"VALUES ('$user_id','$file_name','$file_type','$file_size')"; 
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"image_file/".$file_name);
}
mysql_query($query);        

    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }

if(empty($error)){
    echo '<script type=text/javascript>
alert("Registration was succeed");
window.location.href = "home.php";
</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: where is the `i have tried` part

Comment: Post your source code please.

Comment: From looking at your source code, once the user submits the form it will navigate them to multiple_upload_image.php so your form won't be on display. You can't disable buttons that don't exist. If you change your posting method to using ajax you can post media to your php file and keep the client on the current page.
If you would be interested in using ajax to post media then please check [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674575/php-upload-extract-and-progressbar/26679480#26679480) If you find it to be of any use then please be sure to vote up.

Comment: Yes, I would like to try use ajax , let us check. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set one cookie value to true when upload start and check same cookies value using jquery cookie periodically.

Set cookie value to false where your php code ends for upload.

So this way you will get false in JS cookie code and you can call your button disable js code.

Client Source Code - Javscript

```
function getCookie( name ) {
   var parts = document.cookie.split(name + "=");
   if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

function expireCookie( cName ) {
    document.cookie =  encodeURIComponent( cName ) + "=deleted; expires=" + new Date( 0 ).toUTCString();
}

function setCursor( docStyle, buttonStyle ) {
    document.getElementById( "doc" ).style.cursor = docStyle;
    document.getElementById( "button-id" ).style.cursor = buttonStyle;
}

function setFormToken() {
    var downloadToken = new Date().getTime();
    document.getElementById( "downloadToken" ).value = downloadToken;
    return downloadToken;
}

var downloadTimer;
var attempts = 30;

// Prevents double-submits by waiting for a cookie from the server.
function blockResubmit() {
var downloadToken = setFormToken();
setCursor( "wait", "wait" );

downloadTimer = window.setInterval( function() {
  var token = getCookie( "downloadToken" );

  if( (token == downloadToken) || (attempts == 0) ) {
    unblockSubmit();
  }

      attempts--;
    }, 1000 );
  }

function unblockSubmit() {
    setCursor( "auto", "pointer" );
    window.clearInterval( downloadTimer );
    expireCookie( "downloadToken" );
}
```

Server Code - PHP

```
$TOKEN = "downloadToken";

// Sets a cookie so that when the download begins the browser can
// unblock the submit button (thus helping to prevent multiple clicks).
// The false parameter allows the cookie to be exposed to JavaScript.
$this->setCookieToken( $TOKEN, $_GET[ $TOKEN ], false );

$result = $this->sendFile();
```

Where:

```
public function setCookieToken(
$cookieName, $cookieValue, $httpOnly = true, $secure = false ) {

// See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1459794/59087
// See: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host
// See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3290474/59087
setcookie(
  $cookieName,
  $cookieValue,
  2147483647,            // expires January 1, 2038
  "/",                   // your path
  $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], // your domain
  $secure,               // Use true over HTTPS
  $httpOnly              // Set true for $AUTH_COOKIE_NAME
);
}
```

Comment: Or depending on the method being used to post the upload you could use eventlisteners. If Intan is using ajax to post then using cookies wouldn't be needed. hence waiting for the source code.

Comment: Hi Lalit Sharma - Thank you for your explain. I will try with above your input code. Maybe I still need your help, if I have further concerns or questions.Thank you.