# Loading progress bar while php form post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I found a interesting article [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/12/12/progress-button-styles/), which has a progress bar within the button. I want to implement this while I post a data to php file from a html file.

To be specific, The loading animation should appear when I navigate from HTML to php page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="POST.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is your question? It doesn't appear that you have made any attempts to integrate what you found. If you have please post that code

Comment: Using AJAX and the `progress` even listener. This uses one for image uploading - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674575/php-upload-extract-and-progressbar/26679480#26679480

Comment: I don't know how to implement it! But have made attempts.

Comment: @user2768665 Please show us your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
   $('#processing').show();
   $.ajax({url: 'form.php', data: $(this).serialize(), success:

   function(data) {
      // Process returned data
      $('#processing').hide();
                }});
 return false;
 });
```

Or instead of hide you can load image loading gif.