# JavaScript upload progress bar with xhr.status error 500, but one file loads

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

I've got a problem with a script that is used to upload one or more `multipart/form-data` files.

On my client's server, when I try to upload more than one file, I receive:

> xhr.status error 500;

The first file is uploaded okay, but I can't upload more than 1 file. On my server, everything works fine - there is no `error 500.`

I have searched the web for help, but I could only find information about server problems, such as: can not accept POST, GET, OPTIONS...

But it's working with one file - and I'm stuck.

I tried to upload the files one by one, but then my progress bar is flashing like....

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".errorNotice").hide();
});

var form = document.getElementById('upload-form');
var ident = document.getElementById('ident');
var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-select');
var uploadButton = document.getElementById('submit');
var max = document.getElementById('max');
var formUrl = form.action;

function sleep(milliseconds) {
    setTimeout(function(){ return true; }, milliseconds);
}

form.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Trwa ładowanie...';
    $("#upload-form").fadeOut();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#progressBar").fadeIn();
    }, 500);

    var files = fileSelect.files;
    var formData = new FormData();

    if( files.length > max.value) {
        if( max.value == 1) {
            var text = max.value + ' zdjęcie';
        }
        else if( max.value >1 && max.value <= 4) {
            var text = max.value + ' zdjęcia';
        }
        else {
            var text = max.value + ' zdjęć';
        }
        $("#progressBar").find("p").html('Możesz dodać maksymalnie: ' + text);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#progressBar").hide();
            $("#upload-form").fadeIn();
        }, 5000);
        return false;
    }

    if( files.length == 0 )
    {
        $("#progressBar").hide();
        $("#upload-form").show();
    }

    formData.append('ident', ident.value);
    formData.append('modules', 'true');

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];

        if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        formData.append('objectPhoto[]', file, file.name);
        formData.append(name, file, file.name);
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', formUrl , true);

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
        if(e.lengthComputable) {
            var percentage = Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
            document.getElementById("bar").style.width = percentage + '%';
            document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = percentage + '%';
        }
    }, false);

    xhr.onload = function () {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        if(this.responseText == "ok") {
            document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = "Zakończono";
            document.getElementById("progressBar").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("upload-form").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            $(".errorNotice").show();
            $(".errorNotice .error-text").html(this.responseText);
        }

        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Wgraj';
        } else {
            $(".errorNotice").show();
            $(".errorNotice .error-text").html("Wystąpił nieoczekiwany błąd o kodzie: " + xhr.status);
            uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Wyślij';
        }
    };

    xhr.send(formData);
    return false;
};
```

Comment: If you want to use ajax posting and progress bar check this answer, this answer can almost be change for multiple uploads and display as one progress bar but this is where you need to put in the work. I know because i use the same for my multiple uploading and single uploaing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674575/php-upload-extract-and-progressbar/26679480#26679480

Comment: I've use this example as base to my project.