# Jquery refresh div alter show div time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Jquery script to refresh a div:

```
<script>
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#content').hide();
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#content').show();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#content').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#content");
        $container.load('../../../viewcontent.php');
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('../../../viewcontent.php');
        }, 30000);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Is it possible to alter this script so that it shows the loading div for like 3 seconds and then continue with the complete/success function?

Comment: Put a timeout before the `$('#loading').hide()`?

Comment: This isn't answering how to edit your existing source code to fit your needs but if you don't find a solution, check this answer out. This uses a `progress` event listener

Comment: @NewToJS What answer do you mean?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Display something while waiting async call result?

Comment: @CrisKolkman Sorry for the late reply, I didn't notice the comment submitted but here's the link I referred to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674575/php-upload-extract-and-progressbar/26679480#26679480 That will display the progress %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bad way to do it

```
<script>
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#content').hide();
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    $('#loading').hide(); 
                    $('#content').show();
                }, 3000);

            },
            success: function() {
                 setTimeout(function(){ 
                    $('#loading').hide(); 
                    $('#content').show();
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#content");
        $container.load('../../../viewcontent.php');
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('../../../viewcontent.php');
        }, 30000);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Altough not ideal cause you are bottlenecking your ajax call. It can never go faster then 3 seconds if you use timeout

good way to do it :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/",
  data: {},
  beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    //Upload progress
    XMLHttpRequest.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with upload progress
      }
    }, false); 
    //Download progress
    XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with download progress
      }
    }, false); 
  },
  success: function(data){
    //Do something success-ish
  }
});
```

check out this website for a good reference [HTML5 progress bar ajax](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/)

Comment: Awesome this did the trick, thank you! I removed the first $('#content').hide(); because he also hide the div which contained the loading div.

Comment: @CrisKolkman glad to help you :). Please check my updated answer and mark as answer if it solves your problem thanks in advance