# image upload in server using ajax call and php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a input file ...i want to upload attached file to server with a message uploaded successful when i click on upload button am getting ... file not sent message. (the uploaded images have to be saved in uploads folder.)

```
index.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Camera </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="sample.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
           <form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div style="margin-top:3rem;margin-left: 30%;">
                    <input type="file" name="file1" id="take-picture" accept="image/*" >
               </div>              
                <div style="margin-top: 2rem; margin-left: 10%;">
                    <img src="about:blank" alt="" id="show-picture" height="50%" width="50%">

                </div>
           <div style="margin-top: 3rem;margin-left: 30%;">

              <button id="upload">Upload</button>
              </div>

</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="sample.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>




sample.js

$(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        data = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
        console.log('Submitting');
        alert(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            alert(data);

        }).fail(function(jqXHR,status, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log(jqXHR.status);
        });
    });
});



upload.php

<?php
if($_FILES['img']['error'] > 0) die('Error ' . $_FILES['file']['error']);
if(empty($_FILES['img']['name'])) die('No file sent.');

$tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];

if(is_uploaded_file($tmp))
{
    if(!move_uploaded_file($tmp, '/uploads/')) echo 'error !';

}
else echo 'Upload failed !';
?>


folder---- uploads (where images have to be saved)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674575/php-upload-extract-and-progressbar/26679480#26679480

Answer (score 0):

the $_FILES key in your php does not match the input file on your form...
start by making things match... if your HTML

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" accept="image/*" >
```

Then on PHP

```
$_FILES['file1']['error']...
$_FILES['file1']['name']...
```

Besides...

Did you check permissions on the folder where you want to store the files?

Can a the remote user write to **/uploads/** ?

Comment: <?php
if($_FILES['file1']['error'] > 0) die('Error ' . $_FILES['file1']['error']);
if(empty($_FILES['file1']['name'])) die('No file sent.');

$tmp = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];

if(is_uploaded_file($tmp))
{
    if(!move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'img.png')) echo 'error !';
 
}
else echo 'Upload failed !';
?>

Comment: changed like that but same issue