# Progress bar when updating the database

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sql-update, progress

I have a rather large database that takes a couple of hours to update. Right now I have a spinner that just loads, but the user has no idea how far along it is. I wonder how it would be possible to make a progress bar. The problem is I am not sure how to approach it.

I have not included my method for updating the data in SQL as it is pretty standard. But I can edit the post an add it if needed. However everytime a row has been updated I echo the following line  `$statement->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";`

This is my main method for updating my database

```
function updateDatabase($test, $optionName, $value) {
set_time_limit(0);
global $DAO;
try {
    foreach ($test as $post) {
        $accesToken = "1581461310.56cbc4a.869be6649a604df4874513126692a3ec";
        $updateMedia = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' . $post['insta_id'] . '?access_token=' . $accesToken;
        $insta_stream2 = Connect::instaconn($updateMedia);
        $obj = json_decode($insta_stream2, true);
        if ($obj['meta']['code'] == 200) {
            $DAO->updatePost($post['insta_id'], $obj);
        }
    }
    $DAO->updateSettings($optionName, $value);
    return "Database has been updated";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return "Database has NOT been updated. Error:" . $e;
}
}
```

And I update my database from my `index.html` via an AJAX call

```
            $('#updateDatabase').click(function (e) {
                var r = confirm("Warning: Updating the database can take a long time depending on the size. Do you want to update the database?");                 
                if (r === true) {
                    e.preventDefault();                    
                    var ajaxurl = '../crawler/api_update_dump.php',
                            data = {'action': 'updateDatabase', 'optionName': 'last_update', 'value': currentDate};
                    $.get(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                        // Response div goes here.
                        obj = JSON.parse(response);
                        console.log("response", obj);
                        document.getElementById("lastUpdated").innerHTML = "<font  color='white'>Last Updated: " + new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10) + "</font>";
                    });
                }
            });
```

In my php file the AJAX call is recieved the following way

```
 case 'getLastUpdate':
            $lastUpdate = $DAO->getValueFromTable("value", "settings", "option_name", "last_update", "value");
            echo json_encode($lastUpdate);
            break;
```

Anyone have any suggestions how I should approach making a progress bar for the update?

Comment: You can make another ajax request to check the progress, look into long polling.

Comment: Check this answer out for ajax progress bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674575/php-upload-extract-and-progressbar/26679480#26679480 this uses an event listener, listening for the progress event.